# Getting zero records when using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Everytime I use NSPredicate in fetching my records from CoreData, I always get zero or no records at all. Here's my function:

```
func get_facility(company: String, territory: String){
        print("company: " + company)
        print("territory: " + territory)
        var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let companyPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "company LIKE %@", company)
        let territoryPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "territory LIKE %@", territory)
        let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.OrPredicateType, subpredicates: [companyPredicate, territoryPredicate])
        let fetchRequestFacility = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Facility")

        fetchRequestFacility.predicate = predicate

        do {
            let facility_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestFacility)
            facility = facility_temp as! [Facility]
            c = facility_temp.count
            print(c)
            tableview_facility.reloadData()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // failure
            print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
```

When I comment out the the line `fetchRequestFacility.predicate = predicate` it shows all of my records. The fields company and territory are of type String.

I also tried changing the LIKE keyword to == and =. But I still get no records.

Possible values for `company` = 1 and `territory` = 1. These are numbers but with String data type. And here's the structure of my facility entity:

[image]

I think I found the culprit, when I print the values of company and territory, I get the:

```
company: Optional(1)
territory: Optional(1)
```

And when I try this predicate: `let companyPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "company = '1'")`, I am able to fetch records. Maybe its because the variables company and territory have Optionals string. I don't know how to remove it. I tried putting ! to my variable but still the same.

Comment: You will have to show us the values for `company` and `territory` and the values in you DB.

Comment: Note that `LIKE` uses wildcards - the searched value must be equal to the entity value, possibly with `?` or `*`. Maybe you would like to use `CONTAINS`? You an also directly use predicate `NSPredicate(format: "territory LIKE %@ OR company LIKE %@", territory, company)`

Comment: Give an example or two of strings that you're using in the predicates and the results which you expect to match. From what you've posted so far the most likely answer is that nothing matches, which is why you get zero results.

Comment: Please show the class definition for the `Facility` entity: if the `company` property is a relationship, you need to indicate which attribute of the related object your predicate should compare: e.g. `let companyPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "company.name LIKE %@", company)` will compare the company `name` attribute with the supplied string.

Comment: @TomHarrington I updated the question.

Comment: @pbasdf I updated the question.

Comment: I think your problem is not here but in the way company and territory are passed to the function. If you print them and you get *Optional(1)*, them being `String` and not `String?` means that when you call the function the value inside company is already "Optional(1)". Possibly due to casting an optional Int into a String. So how do you read company and territory and how do you pass them to the function?